# How to force Vim to delete all the [No Name] buffers?

Tags: buffers, argument-list

I often use Vim to manipulate clipboard data.

- I create a new buffer `:enew`
- Paste the data in it
- Modify the data
- Yank it `:%y`

At the end of my day, I end up with several `[No Name]` buffers.

I want to delete `:bd!` from the list of `[No Name]` buffers.

How to do that?

I had the idea to use the `arglist` and to do `:argdo bd!` but I don't know how to populate the `arglist` with the `[No Name]` buffers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way of cleaning up the buffer list](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27104/efficient-way-of-cleaning-up-the-buffer-list)

Comment: So it's a pretty straightforward implementation using getbufinfo and execute. You'll only need to change the filter logic.

Comment: Thanks @Matt I thought there is a solution with the `arglist`. I'll follow your advice :-)

Comment: You could avoid the issue by using a *scratch buffer* (roll your own or use one of the several plugins).

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich, do you recommend one?

Comment: something like this perhaps? `:bufdo if empty(bufname('%'))|bw|endif`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, it works :-) I tried something very similar without success (maybe it was too late ;-) ). Thanks again.

Comment: I seem to be late to answer. I can't really recommend anything. I had the original [scratch.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/scratch.vim) installed and used it now and then. Now that I don't have it, I don't miss it. There days, I'd take a look at its [successor of the same name](https://github.com/mtth/scratch.vim). Also, the [answers to this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/what-is-a-scratch-window) may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich. Never too late to answer. I'll have a look to your plugin proposition :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt You might like [vimclippy](https://normalmo.de/posts/vimclippy/). It's a much more streamlined way to use Vim to edit your clipboard. (N.B. It's not a plugin.)

Comment: @Rich, thanks for the advice. I'll test it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of Friedrich's comment, using scratch buffers instead of regular buffers would seem to be a better strategy.

FWIW, this is a very common use case for me, which I address with the following command:

```
command! SC vnew
        \ | setlocal bufhidden=wipe buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
        \ | nnoremap <buffer> ,<CR> :silent %source<CR>
```

With that, I get a scratch window like this:

[image: scratch window]

From there, you can get fancy with a buffer-local mapping that yanks the buffer and closes the window, setting a default filetype, etc.

It works like this:

- `bufhidden=wipe` wipes out the buffer when it is hidden or when the window is closed,
- `buftype=nofile` prevents accidental write,
- `nobuflisted` prevents the buffer from polluting `:ls`, `:b`, etc.
- `noswapfile` makes sure no swap file is created for that buffer.

See `:help special-buffers`.

NOTE: before the behavior of `:source` was changed, the mapping looked like this:

```
nnoremap <buffer> ,<CR> :silent %y\|@"<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks I like this solution very much. I like to be able to list these buffer too. I'll keep a simple: `command! SC vnew | setlocal buftype=nofile noswapfile`

Comment: Upvoted for flattery. However, the `nnoremap` in the third line seems unrelated to Vivian's question. When just doing some back-of-the-envelope editing, it's hardly ever necessary to `source` the buffer, is it? Or maybe it passed above my head...

Comment: Indeed, OP didn't explicitly ask for that. But I lifted that snippet verbatim from my `vimrc` and I thought that providing a real world example would somehow be helpful. BTW, my ego says thanks for the internet points.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my earlier comments into an answer to preserve them for future readers.*

Instead of creating a lot of unnamed buffers and cleaning them up later, a *scratch buffer* may be used to do back-of-the-envelope editing work. One can write a command to create a scratch buffer or use an existing plugin.

For DIY instructions, refer to the [accepted answer by romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43390/4866) or the answers to [What is a scratch window?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/what-is-a-scratch-window)

There are also some plugins that provide scratch buffers:

The first one to do so was [vim-scripts/scratch.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/scratch.vim), AFAIK. While it doesn't offer a lot functionality, it does one thing and it does it well.

There's also the more modern [mtth/scratch.vim](https://github.com/mtth/scratch.vim) which traces its ancestry back to the original scratch.vim above and adds some configuration options and convenience mappings.

My personal experience is that I used the original plugin occasionally over the course of several years. I don't have it installed any more and I rarely miss it. I never tried out its successor but it looks promising.

I asked myself why I'm not using scratch buffers anymore. I found that I rather start a new instance of Vim, do my editing and throw the garbage away with `:q!` once I'm done. Certainly not the most elegant way to do it. But then, Vim starts instantly and I need to go through system clipboard most of the time, anyway.

Comment: I also have `pbed() { pbpaste | vipe | pbcopy }` on macOS for editing the clipboard. I frequently `:new`, edit, `:bw` for a scratch buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I also like to use Vim to edit my system clipboard, and I wrote a [couple](https://normalmo.de/posts/vimclippy/) of [blogposts](https://normalmo.de/posts/ivimclippy/) about how I've configured my devices to streamline this.

The basic idea is to use Vim's features to automate moving the text from the
clipboard into Vim, and back again after editing, so all you have to do is
actually edit the text.

As I'm generally *not* in Vim when I want to edit my clipboard, I've set up a function in my shell to achieve this (works in at least bash and zsh):

```sh
vimclippy() {
  vim +'silent pu!+' +'$d _' +'1' +'set nomodified' +'au BufWriteCmd vimclippy %y+ | set nomodified' vimclippy
}
```

...but if you want to be able to do this from inside Vim, it's easy to set up a
[command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands), too:

```vim
function! s:vimclippy() abort
  edit vimclippy
  silent put! +
  $delete _
  1
  set nomodified
  augroup vimclippy
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWriteCmd vimclippy %yank + | set nomodified
  augroup END
endfunction

command VimClippy call s:vimclippy()
```

This also allows us to easily create a version that works in the standard Windows command prompt, too<sup>*</sup>, by dropping a file named `vimclippy.bat` somewhere in your `Path` with the contents:

```
vim +VimClippy
```

All the versions work in the same way: starting from an empty buffer, they:

1. `:put` the contents of the system clipboard,
2. `:delete` the extra blank line at the end of the buffer,
3. Move back to the start of the buffer,
4. Set up an [autocommand](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocommand) to replace the normal behaviour of `:w` so that instead of actually writing the buffer, it instead yanks its contents back into the system clipboard.

<sub>*: I'm sure it's easy for someone that knows how to convert the original shell command into something that works in the Windows command prompt so you don't *need* to update your Vim configuration. I am not that person.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll add the command to by `_vimrc`. I'm running on Windows with `set clipboard=unnamed`. The core part of the solution works fine if I replace: `"` by: `*`.  The initial shell command needs also some adaptation to Windows (I suppose I'll manage to adapt it). Maybe starting with the core of the solution avoid that some Windows user reads it :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt If you've already set up the `:command`, then you can just run `vim +VimClippy` in Windows command prompt. I'll update my answer to make it a bit more Windows-friendly. Thanks for the notes!

Comment: it works great thanks. I took the freedom to make two small changes in your solution such that. The clipboard is not modified and if not modification are made in the buffer the user is not forced to save it.

Comment: The missing `set nomodified` was a bug in the function (you'll see it was present in the original shell command), so thanks for fixing it! Using `+` works fine for me though on Windows, and `*` refers to something else in the X11 GUI version, so I reverted that change.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Added some help for Windows users.

Comment: thanks it works fine for me with `+` replaced by `*` and the shell command `gVim +VimClippy`.